# MVC WebAPI application 40+ seconds to launch the webpage

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've developed a web application with MVC 4, WebAPI, EF6, BootStrap, JQuery. It works fine.  But, it takes 40+ seconds to load the webpage. How should I verify, where it is taking too much of time. I heard about pro-filer but which pro-filer I should go for and how to run against my application. Or Is there any other suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a lot of things are happening at the back ;)

What you could do is download [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) from Jetbrains (10 days for free, enough time to solve your issue)

Tell us a bit more about your web application.